# Warning in Pandas using groupby to SQL-like window functions in

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

The following code produce this warning: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

```
self.df_rankpct["rankpct_market_value"] = self.df_rankpct.groupby(['Date'])[
                "market_value"].rank( method ="min")
```

How can I avoid the warning?

Comment: is `df_rankpct` derived from another dataframe? if yes put a `.copy()` to the code  where you define `df_rankpct`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: No, my problem is not solved using df.loc  . See anky answers

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of workarounds:

**1: Modify warning**

If you want to switch of the warning since its not an error, set

```
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', xxx)
```

replace xxx with 'raise' (to raise an exception instead of a warning), 'warn'(to generate default warning), None (to switch off the warning entirely)

**2: Modify is_copy**

Pandas DataFrame has an is_copy property that is None by default but uses a weakref, by setting is_copy to None, this warning can be avoided.

```
self.df_rankpct.is_copy = None
```

**3:  Use loc to slice subsets**

```
self.df_rankpct.loc[:, ['rankpct_market_value']] = self.df_rankpct.groupby(['Date'])["market_value"].rank( method ="min")
```

Please refer to these links:

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

[How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: Thanks so much for the information but the last one(3) doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you try this ? self.df_rankpct.loc[:,['rankpct_market_value']] = self.df_rankpct.groupby(['Date'])["market_value"].rank( method ="min")